# UICollectionView horizontal paging with space between pages

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uipageviewcontroller, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm looking for a way to replace the native `UIPageViewController` horizontal paging with a `UICollectionView`.

so far i did the following:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
layout.itemSize = collectionView.frame.size
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10

collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)
collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
```

this works fine and i get an horizontal paging effect.

Now i want to add horizontal space between the pages (like u will do with `UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey` on `UIPageViewController`)

so far i couldn't fine a way to add the spaces without damaging the paging effect. 
im looking for the same behavior as with the `UIPageViewController`: the cell should fill the entire screen width, and the space between the cells should only be visible when switching a page.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Solution one:

1. `collectionView.isPagingEnabled = false`
2. add a `minimumLineSpacing` for the distance between pages
3. implement `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:` to move the contentOffset to the closest page.  You can calculate the page with simple math based on your `itemSize` and `minimumLineSpacing`, but it can take a little work to get it right.

Solution Two:

1. `collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true`
2. add a `minimumLineSpacing` for the distance between pages
3. the paging size is based on the bounds of the collectionView.  So make the collectionView larger then then screenSize. For example, if you have a `minimumLineSpacing` of 10 then set the frame of the collectionView to be {0,-5, width+10, height}
4. set a contentInset equal to the `minimumLineSpacing` to make the first and last item appear correctly.

Comment: but then it will be hard to duplicate the all paging behavior

Comment: Thanks for the tip, managed to do it by matching the insets like you said `minimumLineSpacing = 20` and `sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 10)` in the CollectionViewLayout

Comment: This is what I am trying to do :

I have a ASPagerNode with three pages.

I am trying to have minimum line spacing of 10 or 20 between the pages.

Then each page is a ASCollectionNode with 3 columns I am trying to have equal spacing between the 3 columns.

I managed to space the 3 columns correctly but the pages are slightly offset to the right and I am struggling to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

- By default, UICollectionViewFlowLayout's minimumLineSpacing is 10.0, when collectionView's item is horizontally filled (itemSize.width = collectionView.bounds.width) and collectionView is paging enabled, greater than zero 'minimumLineSpacing' will cause an unintended performance: start from second page, every page has a gap which will be accumulated by page number.
- It seems that we can expand collectionView's width by 'minimumLineSpacing' to fix this problem. But pratice negates this solution: When there are tow pages or more, collectionView will not give the last one a 'lineSpacing', so it's 'contentSize' is not enough to show this page's content completely, which means if the 'minimumLineSpacing' were 10.0, the last page's end would overstep the collectionView's contentSize by 10.0.
- Finally, I use the following simple solution to insert a margin between every item (like UIScrollView's preformance): Expand every collectionViewItem's width by a fixed value 'pageSpacing' (such as 10.0), and expand the collectionView's width by the same value, too. And don't forget that, when layout collevtionViewCell's subviews, there's an additional spacing which is not for diplaying the real content.

Heres the code written in Swift 3.1, I'm sure it's easily understanding for you:

```
let pageSpacing: CGFloat = 10

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize                = CGSize(width: view.frame.width + pageSpacing, height: view.frame.height)
        layout.scrollDirection         = .horizontal
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing      = 0

        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width + pageSpacing, height: view.frame.height)
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
    }
}

class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    var fullScreenImageView = UIImageView()
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        fullScreenImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width - pageSpacing, height: frame.height)
    }
}
```

Hope that can help you.